# How to change the mouse pointer to finger pointer in swing?

Tags: java, swing, mouseover, jlabel

In html when we create a hyperlink and point over it ,then it automatically changes to a finger pointer.

So I was wondering can we achieve the same in java swings.
Suppose I have a label on clicking which a new form pops-up.But I want that when the user points over the label it should change to finger pointer,showing that something will pop-up if its clicked.In this way we can differentiate that label with normal labels on the form i guess :).

But how to do something like this?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can set cursor of JLabel to [Cursor.HAND_CURSOR](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Cursor.html#HAND_CURSOR) using below code :

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("https://stackoverflow.com");
label.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
```

Comment: Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);

Comment: MadProgrammer's approach is the better one. It avoids the unneccesary creation of a `Cursor` object, provided that it has been created before.

Answer (score 2):

go to the properties of the button or the label and scroll down you will find a column of cursor you can change to hand or whatever you want

Answer (score 1):

As said you'd want to call the `setCursor()` method on the JLabel and set it to `Cursor.Hand_CURSOR` to further this you can also underline the text to make it an HTML look alike link if you want :):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.net.URI;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/**
 *
 * @author ludovicianul
 */
public class URLLabel extends JLabel {

    private String url;

    public URLLabel() {
        this("","");
    }

    public URLLabel(String label, String url) {
        super(label);

        this.url = url;
        setForeground(Color.BLUE.darker());
        setCursor(
                new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        addMouseListener(
                new URLOpenAdapter());
    }

    public void setURL(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    //this is used to underline the text
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.setColor(Color.blue);

        Insets insets = getInsets();

        int left = insets.left;
        if (getIcon() != null) {
            left += getIcon().getIconWidth() + getIconTextGap();
        }

        g.drawLine(left, getHeight() - 1 - insets.bottom, (int) getPreferredSize().getWidth()
                - insets.right, getHeight() - 1 - insets.bottom);
    }

    private class URLOpenAdapter extends MouseAdapter {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                try {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(url));
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    //
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Reference:**

- [CREATING A URL JLABEL IN SWING](https://insidecoding.wordpress.com/2011/09/05/creating-a-url-jlabel-in-swing/)

Comment: I feel URL feel is sufficient only by the below two line of code.

`JLabel mylabel=new JLabel("<html><u>Click here</u></html>");
mylabel.setForeground(Color.BLUE.darker());`

Comment: @Abhinav And I dont disagree. I just love writing code in its pure form :P

Answer (score 0):

**Hossein Mobasher**
 answer is good and mine answer is very late but i just want to add up you can also use it like this below.

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("http://stackoverflow.com");
label.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
```

It will also work i have tried it in Java 1.8

Answer (score 0):

ButtonName.SetCursor(new Cursor(12));
This one works definitely!