# How can I get the path of a file's icon in Java?

Tags: java, windows

How can I get the file path of a windows 10 file/shortcut using java. I have tried importing the icon itself but it is always too small and I need it to be full sized, and I can't seem to find a way to import the full sized version without getting the ico's file path manually.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686938/how-to-change-the-mouse-pointer-to-finger-pointer-in-swing/11687002#11687002

Comment: @JEngineer This is nothing to do with my question

Comment: [Windows 10/11 icons](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/where-find-most-windows-10s-native-icons/) are contained within DLL files.  How are you reading these files in Java?

Comment: It may help me (and possibly others) to answer your question if you provide more details. Can you post an example icon - both in the size you are getting and the size you want to get? Can you post the code that imports the icon?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the icon from Window's **regedit.exe**. Read the comments:

[image]

```
/**
 * Retrieves the Icon from a Windows executable file and returns it as Icon 
 * type.
 * <p>
 * <b>Example Usage:</b><pre>
 * {@code 
 * // Retrieve the icon from Window's 'regexe.exe' and set it into a 
 *  // JLabel declared as 'jLabel1':
 *  Icon icon = getWindowsExecutableIcon("c:/windows/regedit.exe");  
 *  jLabel1.setIcon(icon);
 * }</pre>
 * 
 * @param filePath (String) The full path and file name of the Window's 
 * executable file to get the icon from.<br>
 * 
 * @return (Icon)
 */
public static Icon getWindowsExecutableIcon(String filePath) {
    return javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView.getFileSystemView()
         .getSystemIcon(new java.io.File(filePath));
}
```